in eclipse, if two branch in git with many different in library dependencies, should use same workspace or different workspace?
I know for two branches in git with source different, we can use same eclipse workspace and switch branch.
But if two branches have many different in library dependecies also (one branch support JBOSS 7, spring 5, ...etc, another branch support JBOSS 8, spring 6, ...), should still use the same eclipse workspace and switch branch for JBOSS 7 and 8?
My project is maven-based project.
